# exclude some files from synchronization with SVN , eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is it possible to exclude/ignore some specific files from synchronization with SVN that are present in svn ??

These files are already present in SVN, and I believe from other posts that the `rightClick->Team->SVN:IGnore` only works for files that are not there in svn.

I have read other posts but can not find the answer.

Reason : we have some files that have some specific content in SVN while some other content in local workspace, People by mistake are checking in theirversion of these config files to SVN.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is an easier way to do it, but following should work:

1. Optional: save your file somewhere, in case you can't recreate it
2. Open 'SVN Repositories' view, navigate to location of file you don't want to be in SVN, right click on it and choose 'Delete'. This would remove file from repository
3. Synchronize. You would see file removal as incoming change. Accept it. This would remove file from your local file system
4. Recreate file in your local file system, or copy from step (1). File would show as outgoing change if you synchronize at this point.
5. Now you should be able to do 'Right click->Team->Add to SVN Ignore' on it. Do this and commit property change on the folder.

Comment: Correct. I think you indicated that people checked it in by mistake so I presume you desired that file should not be in SVN :)

Comment: I think I was not much clear. there is a file `a.xml` in svn and on my workspace as well. these two files have different contents and i do not want my workspace version to override the one in svn. Now when i sync I see outgoing changes on `a.xml`, I want this file to be ignored so I dont see this as some people are careless enough to check this file in despite clear warnings.. :)

Comment: If that's the case I don't think you would be able to use svnignore. Perhaps look at SVN commit hook to only grant specific users ability to change/commit these reserved files.

Comment: hmmm.. editing privileges is not an option for me. Thanks for your quick help though. :)

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) has a option in the Windows-context-menu by right-clicking on the file to unversioncontrol and add to ignore list. The action should also be recogniced by the plugin, even if the plugin menu has not this option.

If you do not want to use Tortoise for this, a simple workaround would be:

- remove the files from the folder(store them temporaly else where)
- commit, the removed files.
- if you are not on the commiting computer update now
- paste back in the removed files and add them to the ignore list.

Comment: In the workaround for all newer versions: yes. But you can still revert to an earlier version to restore the file. By the unversioncontrol option the file will no longer be updated but not removed on an update, as I know.  Better try this in a test SVN setting first ;)